# Edit String in a Vector

Tags: java, string, vector

I'm looking for a way to edit a `String` contained in a `Vector`, like this:

```
vector.lastElement()=vector.lastElement()+"\n"+string;
```

I get the following compilation error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: In addition to the actual error, you should almost never use `Vector` in new code. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Left side of the `=` operator will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it this way. `vector.lastElement()` returns a String (in your case). You can assign this String to a variable, but you can't assign anything to it.

In addition, since String is immutable, you can't change the String contained within the Vector.

What you can do it replace the last element of the Vector with a new String :

```
vector.setElementAt(vector.lastElement()+"\n"+string,vector.size()-1);
```

Comment: I don't think immutability is the issue here, `vector.lastElement()` is not a valid lvalue.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen But I think because OP can do what he want by using Eran's code, it is okay.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen You're right. That wasn't the main issue. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

What happens is that you invoke a function `vector.lastElement()` which will return the last element.
If you want to set the last element you have to invoke

```
vector.set(vector.size() -1 , vector.lastElement()+"\n"+string)
```